# Help with understanding Semaphore grants in OpenNetworkConnection

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, json-rpc, network

I am new to concurrent programming. Can any expert throw some light on the semaphore grant that one requires before acquiring a network connection ?

```
bool OpenNetworkConnection(const CAddress& addrConnect, CSemaphoreGrant *grantOutbound, const char *pszDest, bool fOneShot)
```

I also notice that while we give `onetry` in `addnode` command of RPC client, the grant is taken as NULL.